# Como crear un túnel ssh port forwarding en Mac con una llave privada

Tags: macos, ssh, port

Estoy tratando de hacer un túnel ssh port forwarding en Mac para conectarme a un servicio de Redshift con una llave privada pem. Estoy tratando de igualar la conexión como en Windows pero en Mac tanto por consola o por herramientas shh no he podido crear la conexión correctamente ssh. La idea es conectarme a un destination server desde un ssh server haciendo forward port con llave privada en Mac.

Esto hago en windows con llave privada .pem con MobaXterm:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

La idea es hacer esto mismo en Mac, alguien conoce una manera de crear un túnel ssh con estos requisitos.

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: creo que tu problema tiene que ver con el sitio  https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ya hizo exclamación del problema

Comment: Todo lo exclamado es off-topic ; no es un problema de programación; es un problema usando una aplicación para crear un tunel SSH puede ser cualquier problema relacionado al Sistema Operativo; no es algo que se resuelva en este sitio...